# Searchbox doesn't fit all the space

Tags: html, css, angular

In my angular project I want that the search bar of my navigation bars, fulfil all the space that it have. I've tried a lot of settings for example width 100% and similar, what's the problem?

this is my code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a (click)=cercaProdotti() style="cursor: pointer;">Ricerca Prodotti</a>
  <a (click)=cercaCorsi() style="cursor: pointer;">Ricerca Corsi</a>
  <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Clients</a>
  <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" (click)="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sapientia&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarCollapse" >
  &nbsp;
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
          data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Tutte le categorie
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" (click)=cercaCorsi() style="cursor: pointer;">Corsi</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" (click)=cercaProdotti() style="cursor: pointer;">Prodotti</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filter" placeholder="Cerca" name="filter">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="refresh()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <font color="#e0a800">Account</font>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Accedi</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Registrati</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">
      <font color="#e0a800">Resi e ordini</font>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">
      <font color="#e0a800">Carrello <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></font>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css file

```css
.form-inline {
  width: 100;
}
```

Comment: maybe a typo? `.form-inline{ width: 100%; }`

Comment: is 100% i'm omitted the % symbol sorry

Comment: Set the `input-group-append` class `width` to `100%` which is inside the `form-inline`